# Generating a CSR in Python

Tags: python, pki, csr

I'm trying to generate a CSR in Python without using OpenSSL. If someone could point in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Are you not able to use any toolkit, or just OpenSSL?

PKCS#10 (cert request format) is fairly simple if you have access to an ASN.1 encoder.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you don't want to use the command line openssl itself and a Python lib is ok.

Here is an helper function I wrote to create a CSR.  It returns the private key from the generated key pair and the CSR.  The function depends on pyOpenSSL.crypto.

```
def create_csr(self, common_name, country=None, state=None, city=None,
               organization=None, organizational_unit=None,
               email_address=None):
    """
    Args:
        common_name (str).

        country (str).

        state (str).

        city (str).

        organization (str).

        organizational_unit (str).

        email_address (str).

    Returns:
        (str, str).  Tuple containing private key and certificate
        signing request (PEM).
    """
    key = OpenSSL.crypto.PKey()
    key.generate_key(OpenSSL.crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)

    req = OpenSSL.crypto.X509Req()
    req.get_subject().CN = common_name
    if country:
        req.get_subject().C = country
    if state:
        req.get_subject().ST = state
    if city:
        req.get_subject().L = city
    if organization:
        req.get_subject().O = organization
    if organizational_unit:
        req.get_subject().OU = organizational_unit
    if email_address:
        req.get_subject().emailAddress = email_address

    req.set_pubkey(key)
    req.sign(key, 'sha256')

    private_key = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(
        OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key)

    csr = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate_request(
               OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, req)

    return private_key, csr
```

Answer (score 1):

[m2crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto) could be a solution (see [CreateX509Request in the contrib example](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/contrib/SimpleX509create.py)), although it relies OpenSSL.

You could also use [python-nss](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/PythonNSS), which uses [Mozilla's NSS library](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/). `nss.nss.CertificateRequest` was added quite recently. The API documentation available at the moment on the website isn't up to date, but here are some pointers for newer versions:

- http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=6444
- http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=185589

It's also in CVS:

```
:pserver:anonymous@cvs-mirror.mozilla.org:/cvsroot/mozilla/security/python/nss
```

Answer (score -6):

Like any language, Python just implements algorithms.  I know next to nothing about cryptography, but if I had to implement this in Python, I would look for a specification on how to implement CSR.

Via Google and Wikipedia I found [this RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986).  Your task would be to implement this in Python.

Personally I'd probably first try to use a the command line tool (perhaps via a call to the `system()` function if it needed to be from Python).