# Python subprocess problem

Tags: python, openssl, pipe, csr

I'm writing a script to generate a CSR in Python. The script is very simple. I generate an RSA private key by using the following:

```
keycmd = "openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 2048"
keyprocess = Popen(keycmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

csrcmd = "openssl req -new -key mykey.pem -subj "+ subj + " -out mycsr.csr"
reqprocess = Popen(csrcmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
```

However, I want to add the functionality to encrypt the private key with a password is the user desires. This is normally done by including the option "-des3" in the genrsa command, but I don't know how to pipe a string from Python standard input to the OpenSSL process. Any help would be appreciated.

What I want to do is:

```
keycmd = "openssl genrsa -des3 -out mykey.pem 2048"
keyprocess = Popen(keycmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
keyprocess.communicate("password")
keyprocess.communicate("password")
```

It's not working however, the script just freezes and never gets past the first communicate statement.

Comment: Did you try the solutions I suggested in your previous similar question? (m2crypto or python-nss).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215780/generating-a-csr-in-python/3450770

Comment: I'd rather not have to download an external library. The code I'm writing is meant to be portable and I don't want people to have to download anything except OpenSSL. Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the option `-passout stdin` to the `openssl genrsa` command, and it will read the passphrase from standard input. That should allow you to send it in via `communicate`.

There are several other values you can provide to the `-passout` option to obtain the passphrase from another source. See the [OpenSSL man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html) for details.

Comment: I'm entering the following into the shell:
openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem -passout stdin 1024

It waits for input from stdin. I type in a word and press Enter. However, the private key generated is not encrypted. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you didn't provide the `-des3` option. `-passout` only tells OpenSSL to read a password from the given source, it doesn't tell it to use the password for anything.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) module ?

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn(keycmd)
child.expect("Enter pass phrase")
child.sendline("password")

child.expect("Verifying - Enter pass phrase")
child.sendline("password")
```